# How to use http client to make the below HTTPS call

Tags: android, https, http-headers

I am trying to integrate payfort payment gateway in my Android application, and I read the documentation link below  https://docs.start.payfort.com/guides/mobile/
Their they gave to insert card details use http client to make below HTTPS call to the start API:

**curl https://api.start.payfort.com/tokens/ \ -u test_open_k_e17270be565ef1b574ba: \ -d "number=4242424242424242" \ -d "exp_month=11" \ -d "exp_year=2016" \ -d "cvc=123" \ -d "name=Abdullah Mohammed"**

Please help me out
Thank you

Comment: what do you have so far? already checked this? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @M.Ali were you able to create token for card. i am stuck too need help.